# How to regenerate the new FCM Token when android app gets logout and login with another user

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

My application is not refreshing  the FCM Token when user logged out. then another user logged in with new credentials its using same FCM token. so notifications are delivering to wrong user.

kindly help me fix this issue. thanks in advance.

***code to generate Token:***

```
@Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) 
    {
        super.onNewToken(token);
       
            Log.d(TAG, "token: " + token);

      }
```

Comment: when the device is same, notification will be received whether token is same or different

Comment: you need to check the user id when notification is received to make sure it does show for new user

Comment: there is no option to clear the Token ? @Quicklearner

Answer (score 1):

You probably store the user/device token on you database and use it to send the FCM message. When a user logs out you would need to delete that token before logging him out. If you try to do it after you would probably have permission errors (make sure that a user can only delete his own tokens).

When a user logs in sync his token to your database. Othervise when you don't dele a token from a user who logged out you would get notifications for every user who logged in your app on the same device.